# Kotlin class works not as expected

Tags: class, kotlin

Here's the code in Kotlin.

*file1*

```
fun main() {
    var player = Player("madrigal")
    println(player.name)

    printPlayerStatus(player)
    println(player.name)
}

private fun printPlayerStatus(player: Player) {
    println("${player.name} ")
}
```

*file2*

```
package com.bignerdranch.nyethack

import java.io.File

class Player(
    _name: String,
    var healthPoints: Int = 100,
    var isBlessed: Boolean,
    private val isImmortal: Boolean
) {

    constructor(name: String) : this(name, isBlessed = true, isImmortal = false) {
        if (name.toLowerCase() == "kar") healthPoints = 40
    }



    var name = _name
        get() ="${field.capitalize()} of $hometown"
        private set(value) {
            field = value.trim()
        }


    val hometown: String = selectHometown()

    init {
        require(healthPoints > 0, { "healthPoints must be greater than zero." })
        require(name.isNotBlank(), { "Player must have a name" })
    }

    private fun selectHometown(): String = File("data/towns.txt")
        .readText()
        .split('\n')
        .shuffled()
        .last()


    fun castFireball(numFireballs: Int = 2) =
        println("A glass of Fireball springs into existence. (x$numFireballs)")

    fun formatHealthStatus() =
        when (healthPoints) {
            100 -> "is in excellent condition!"
            in 90..99 -> "has a few scratches."
            in 75..89 -> if (isBlessed) {
                "has some minor wounds, but is healing quite quickly!"
            } else {
                "has some minor wounds."
            }
            in 15..74 -> "looks pretty hurt."
            else -> "is in awful condition!"
        }

    fun auraColor(): String {
        val auraVisible = isBlessed && healthPoints > 50 || isImmortal
        val auraColor = if (auraVisible) "GREEN" else "NONE"
        return auraColor
    }
}
```

When I run it I get the results:

```
Madrigal of Boston

Madrigal of Boston
```

However, I expect to get the results without the empty string in the middle. Like this:

```
Madrigal of Boston
Madrigal of Boston
Madrigal of Boston
```

Then I rewrite the function printPlayerStatus as below :

```
private fun printPlayerStatus(player: Player) {
    println(player.name)
}
```

Now the output is correct.

Actually I copy the code from the book. And according to the book the code should work fine.

Please, help me to understand why it happens and find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. If I avoid working with file and make a simple list of strings, the output gets as expected.